# Trouble with hosting a django app on digital ocean

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

When I visit **http://[ip address]**, I get a 502 bad request error.

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mainuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/mainuser/Personal_Web
ExecStart=/home/mainuser/Personal_Web/vr/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [ip address];

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mainuser/Personal_Web;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

When I run **sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log**, I get a `connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` error. Im not sure why im getting this or how to fix it?

Comment: Please show the output of "sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket" and "sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket"

Comment: The first one showed:

 ```● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Thu 2021-06-10 14:59:38 UTC; 2h 47min ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)```

The second command showed:

```Listening on gunicorn socket.
Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.```

@EneP

Answer (score 0):

I think you configured this line wrong.

```
ExecStart=/home/mainuser/Personal_Web/vr/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      myapp.wsgi:application
```

Are you sure that **myapp** in `myapp.wsgi:application` is your main folder within your Django project? Your main folder is the folder which contains settings.py and wsgi.py.

Can you try changing it to `name_main_folder.wsgi:application`?